# Composer downloads entire .git repo directory

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php, packagist

I recently published my library in [GitHub](https://github.com/mikemix/zend2-auth) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/mikemix/zend2-auth). When I load it to a project, using the Composer, entire repo is being downloaded, along with the hidden .git directory.

How to prevent Composer from downloading this unnecesary directory?

Comment: Please provide a link to your library on GitHub and Packagist. Maybe it's a problem with your setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer will clone a repository if you do require a development version. And if you reduce the allowed minimum-stability of your application, ALL possible packages are being cloned.

This is actually a good thing because you seem to be in development mode, and after the initial cloning updating these repositories is usually faster - and you can more easily edit these packages and push your changes back.

I tested your package, and it was correctly downloaded as a ZIP file with this `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mikemix/zend2-auth": ">=1.0"
    }
}
```

And after deleting `/vendor` and the composer cache, it cloned your repo with this `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mikemix/zend2-auth": ">=1.0@dev"
    }
}
```

Changing back to the above version, but not deleting anything, a run of `composer update` only checked out that tag, but did not download the ZIP file.

So Composer tries to minimize network activity, and tries to not destroy an existing repository, because that repo might have some valuable code committed in another branch.

Comment: This was very educative. Thank you.